# Set with two elements and an associative binary operation on it which is not commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want an example of a set with two elements and associative binary operation on it which is not commutative. How can we define an associative operation on a set with two elements?

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the set with binary operation $\circ$. If you want to prove that $\circ$ is associative on $S$, then you need to show $a \circ ( b \circ c) = (a \circ b) \circ c$ for all $a,b,c \in S$. Now, if $S$ has two elements, then amongst your $a,b,c$, some of them are going to coincide.

Let's say that $S = \{x,y\}$. Notice we have two choices for $a$, two choices for $b$, and two choices for $c$, so that means can verifying that $\circ$ is associative by checking that the following $2^3 = 8$ equalities hold:

$$x \circ ( x \circ x) = (x \circ x) \circ x$$
$$x \circ ( x \circ y) = (x \circ x) \circ y$$
$$x \circ ( y \circ x) = (x \circ y) \circ x$$
$$x \circ ( y \circ y) = (x \circ y) \circ y$$
$$y \circ ( x \circ x) = (y \circ x) \circ x$$
$$y \circ ( x \circ y) = (y \circ x) \circ y$$
$$y \circ ( y \circ x) = (y \circ y) \circ x$$
$$y \circ ( y \circ y) = (y \circ y) \circ y.$$

EDIT: Just saw the part regarding commutativity. We can define the operation by creating a table where the value of $a \circ b$ is found by looking for the row labeled $a$ and cross-referencing that with the column labeled $b$. Since $\circ$ is a binary operation, it is closed so we can only fill the table with $x$'s and $y$'s.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\circ& x & y \\ \hline
x & & \\ \hline
y &  & \\ 
\end{array}
$$

If we want $\circ$ to not be commutative, that means there exists $a,b \in S$ such that $a \circ b \neq b \circ a$. Notice we can't pick both $a$ and $b$ to be $x$ since we know $x \circ x = x \circ x$. Similarly, we can't pick $a$ and $b$ to both be $y$. The only choice that gives us is that it *must* be the case that $x \circ y \neq y \circ x$. Without loss of generality, I'm going to let $x \circ y = x$. Since $y \circ x \neq x \circ y$, the only choice we have for $y \circ x$ is that $y \circ x = y$. Updating our table,

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\circ& x & y \\ \hline
x & &x \\ \hline
y & y & \\ 
\end{array}
$$

We still need to define $x \circ x$ and $y \circ y$. First, let us suppose that $x \circ x = y$. From associativity we have,
$$x \circ ( x \circ x) = (x \circ x) \circ x$$
$$\implies x \circ (y) = (y) \circ x,$$

a contradiction since $x \circ y \neq y \circ x$. That must mean that $x \circ x = x$. Using a similar argument, one can show that it must be the case that $y \circ y = y$. Thus, our table is complete:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\circ& x & y \\ \hline
x & x &x \\ \hline
y & y & y \\ 
\end{array}
$$

So if $\circ$ is not commutative then this must be how our binary operation is defined (you would have gotten a very similar table if we had instead assumed that $x \circ y = y$ instead).

It remains to show that $\circ$ is actually associative though. Looking at our table though, there is a pattern we see: the result of the operation is only dependent on the row. In other words, for any $a,b \in S$, we can define $\circ$ as $a \circ b = a$. From this, we can observe for any $a,b,c \in S$,
$$a \circ (b \circ c) = a \circ (b) = a$$
$$(a \circ b) \circ c  = (a) \circ c = a$$
and thus $a \circ (b \circ c)  = (a \circ b) \circ c$.

Comment: Brother, Now I can understand how can define associative operation on the set with TWO element But What about "which is not commutative" I can not understand that part of question.

Comment: @user354069 I edited my answer to address the non-commutativity.

Answer (score 1):

There are only sixteen possible binary operations on a two-element set $\{a,b\}$, since for each of the four inputs for the operation, we have two choices for the output. Since we are interested only in noncommutative binary operations, we must have $ab=a$ and $ba=b$ or $ab=b$ and $ba=a$. For both of these possibilities, we are free to pick the value of $a^2$ and $b^2$, so there are eight noncommutative binary operations on $\{a,b\}$.

**Case 1: ab=a and ba=b**

To satisfy associativity, we must have $$b=ba=b(ab)=(ba)b=bb,$$ and $$a=ab=a(ba)=(ab)a=aa.$$

so the operation is defined by:
$$aa=a\quad bb=b\quad ab=a\quad ba=b$$

**Case 2: ab=b and ba=a**

To satisfy associativity, we must have $$b=ab=(ba)b=b(ab)=bb,$$ and $$a=ba=(ab)a=a(ba)=aa.$$

so the operation is defined by:
$$aa=a\quad bb=b\quad ab=b\quad ba=a$$

Of course, we have not proved that either of these are fully associative, but these are the only two candidates, and the complete checks are not hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

For the operation to not be commutative we must have $a*b \ne b*a$.  So one equals $a $ and the other $b$.  Without loss of generality we may assume $a*b=a;b*a=b $.

Associativity now forces our hand I think.

If $a*a=b $ then $a*a*a=(a*a)*a=ba=b $ but $a*a*a=a*(a*a)=a*b=a $.  So $a*a=a$.

The same argument shows $b*b=b $.

So we have $a*a=a;a*b=a;b*a=b;b*b=b $.  That *must* be the answer

... if there is one.

We must show that is associative:

Notice this simplifies to: $a*x=a;b*x=b $ no matter whether $x$ is $a$ or $b $.

In fact we can simplify it further: $x*y=x $

So $(x*y)*z=x*z=x $ while $x*(y*z)=x $

So yes it is associative.

Note had we chosen $a*b=b;b*a=a $ we'd have wound up with the operation $x*y =y $.  Similar but one is "everything equals to the left" and the other is "everything equals to the right".